# Codeigniter - Active record Where Join column ambiguous

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem with active record in codeigniter.

Here is my sql

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('news as n');
    $this->db->join('user as u', 'n.id_user = u.id_user');
    $this->db->where('like >','10');
    $this->db->limit(10);
    $this->db->offset($offset);
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    return $query->result_array();
```

The "**news**" table containing column '**like**' and table "**user**" also containing column "**like**"

and the output is below:

Column 'like' in where clause is ambiguous

```
SELECT * FROM (`news` as n) 
    JOIN `user` as u ON `n`.`id_user` = `u`.`id` 
    WHERE `like` > '10' LIMIT 5
```

Then I replace

```
 $this->db->where('like >','10');
```

with

```
 $this->db->where('n.like >','10');
```

because i want like in news table... But it didn't work

Any solution?

Comment: use  $this->db->where('n.like >','10'); in where clause

Comment: i have try that code.. didn't work

Comment: wait you have "like" as column name?

Comment: in that case put that in quote? and better alter that column name

Comment: do you mean news as n?? if column i dont know where to put like as column name...

Comment: I meant, like is a mysql reserved word, you shouldn't be using it as col name, in case ur using it wrap the column within quote. check my answer

Comment: yes,'like' is a reserved keyword of mysql.@Khawer Zeshan is right,you have to change the field name to something else.

Comment: When you say changing from $this->db->where('like >','10'); to $this->db->where('n.like >','10'); didn't work, do you mean you got the same ambiguous error, or you got a different error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use alias of news table which is `n` so `n.like`

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('news as n');
$this->db->join('user as u', 'n.id_user = u.id_user');
$this->db->where('n.like >','10');
$this->db->limit(10);
$this->db->offset($offset);
$query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result_array();
```

This will still not work as `like` is a reserved keyword of mysql. You need to change the column name to something else. Read more about mysql reserved keywords [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 1):

In case you have "like" as column name, put the column in apostrophes(`) like

```
$this->db->where('`like` >','10');
```

However is not a good practice to use any mysql reserved keywords as an identifier. Alter the column name to else and if you multiple table using the like column use table alias like.

```
$this->db->where('n.`like` >','10');
```

Comment: `db` active record automatic add apostrophe (`) no need

Comment: so you think this is the reason for downvote the answer?

Comment: please read the answer properly before down-voting an answer.

Comment: i have seen your answer, this is not solution at all, if you using query in `$this->db->query()` then there will need `apostrophe` and OP is manipulating query using methods so CI db library will automatic add apostrophe.

Comment: man, I don't want to be in an argument, I have have also mentioned to user table aliases.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('news as n');
    $this->db->join('user as u', 'n.id_user = u.id_user');
    $this->db->where('n.`like` >','10');
    $this->db->limit(10);
    $this->db->offset($offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Note : change your column name to something other than reserved keyword

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you can avoid reserved keywords, so change like column name to likes for instance.

```
$this->db->where('n.likes >', 10);
```